# image analysis - locate pixel groups - desperately need efficient loop

Tags: loops, image-processing, pytorch

i'm implementing my own face detector on pytorch.
currently stuck having a matrix of probabilities for a face being in some location.
i'm trying to write an efficient loop that will count the number of consecutive non zero pixels and tell me  how many pixels are there in each consecutive group.

[image]

so in this example i would get let's say a dictionary blobs = {2:[(8,5),(9,6)],1:[(7,0)],21:[(1,9),(2,7),(2,8),(2,9),(2,10),(3,7)...,]}

```
len(dict) = #number of separate pixels groups
dict.keys() = #how many pixels in each group
dict.values() = #location of each pixel in said group
```

i started making a solution but i have a feeling there is a more elegant one that might be found with the help of this great forum (:

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need to count consecutive non-zero pixels? Adding it as part of the question would provide us with useful information.

Comment: i wan't to reduce the number of false positives so thought of adding a term that treats a "blob" as a face is it contains more than x pixels and also collaps their coordinate into one

Comment: Can you show an example of a true positive case, and a false positive case, and how counting the number of non-zero pixels can help to find the false positive?